Configure chezmoi with run script that doesn't appear in diff?
I want to run a script every time I apply my chezmoi config but I can't figure out how to configure chezmoi so that it doesn't appear as a diff. As an example, I've created a run_hello_world.sh.tmpl file in the root of my chezmoi directory, as below:
❯ cat run_hello_world.sh.tmpl
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Hello, world!"

I want chezmoi diff to return no differences but I get the below diff:
❯ chezmoi diff
diff --git a/hello_world.sh b/hello_world.sh
new file mode 100755
index 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000..476a1a85ff7300eb4134d2d68117523083037243
--- /dev/null
+++ b/hello_world.sh
@@ -0,0 +1,3 @@
+#!/usr/bin/env bash
+
+echo "Hello, world!"

If I put **/hello_world.sh into my .chezmoiignore file, the diff goes away but the script doesn't run. I want to the script to run and for the diff to not appear. Any ideas?

Are you sure this is the right prefix for the script? https://www.chezmoi.io/user-guide/use-scripts-to-perform-actions/#understand-how-scripts-work
It seems that you might want run_onchange_ instead

Thanks for the suggestion – I found it in the docs on the diff page rather than the scripts page

Yes I have found the docs a bit lacking and started to investigate the use through other people's public repo

From the docs, you can do this by configuring chezmoi to exclude "chezmoi scripts" from chezmoi diff, as below.
Using yaml:
diff:
  exclude:
    - scripts

Using toml:
[diff]
    exclude = ["scripts"]


Where "chezmoi scripts" refers to any scripts that chezmoi determines are related to chezmoi's operation, I guess by looking if there are any run_, run_onchange_, etc. prefixes, or a .tmpl suffix.
